# Repository Bean Creation Error with multiple data sources

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I have to deal with two different data sources in my application. I am required to observe xml based configuration, else there are plenty of solutions online for class level configuration.

Below is my configuration:

**Spring-jpa.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


        <!-- JPA Configurations -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <!-- Product Datasource -->
        <bean id="transactionManagerProduct" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryProduct" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactoryProduct"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="productPersistence" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="productDS" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.soft.paramount.model.product, com.soft.paramount.repository.product" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- MDM Datasource -->
        <bean id="transactionManagerMdm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryMdm" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactoryMdm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mdmPersistence" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="mdmDS" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.soft.paramount.model.mdm, com.evantagesoft.panasonic.repository.mdm" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="productDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/productDB" />
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />        
        </bean>
        <bean id="mdmDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/mdmDB" />
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />        
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**spring-api.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.soft.paramount.api, com.evantagesoft.panasonic.servcie" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

I must be doing or missing something in configuration. When I execute my application it return exception as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRegisteredService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productRegisteredService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRegisteredRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.soft.paramount.repository.mdm.product.ProductRegisteredRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productRegisteredService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRegisteredRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.soft.paramount.repository.mdm.product.ProductRegisteredRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.soft.panasonic.repository.mdm.product.ProductRegisteredRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 37 more
```

I have also tried to give repository path under component scan, but didn't work.

Comment: As the error says, there is no bean for `ProductRegisteredRepository`. Are you even creating a bean of this class?

Comment: yes, "ProductRegisteredRepository" is spring jpa interface. Trying to initialize the same via auto-wring.

Comment: Are you missing `@Repository` on top of that interface? Add your `ProductRegisteredRepository` class here.

Comment: com.soft.paramount.repository.mdm.product.ProductRegisteredRepository is in **com.soft.paramount.repository.mdm.product** package. But you have written `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.soft.paramount.model.product, com.soft.paramount.repository.product" />`. please check package details.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding the following lines into my **spring-jpa.xml**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.soft.paramount.repository.mdm" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryMdm"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.soft.paramount.repository.product" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryProduct"/>
```